# solr dataimport from mysql dies when mysq query limit is removed

Tags: mysql, solr, dataimporthandler, large-data

I have a mysql database with over 400,000,000 records in one table.

The Solr import runs fine when I set a limit. My last test was 10,000,000 and it ran successfully in about 5 minutes. Having the full dataset in Solr is required and when I remove the limit, solr is reporting that it has lost the connection to mysql.

I believe that I am running into what seems to be a misconfiguration or a limitation with my current configuration.

Here is the catalina.out log from tomcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT id as solr_id, id,firstname, lastname, state from names Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:621)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:327)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:225)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT id as solr_id, id,firstname, lastname, state from names Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.pullRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:330)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:296)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:683)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:619)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 353,135 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 353,135 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2243)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1999)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3504)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3198)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2366)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2789)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2758)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:246)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 17 bytes, read 12 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2224)
        ... 24 more
Jun 16, 2013 4:51:37 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: start rollback
Jun 16, 2013 4:51:37 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: end_rollback
```

MySQL Log

```
130616 16:15:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130616 16:15:29 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 53687091200 adjusted to 1073741824
130616 16:15:29  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 22.0G
130616 16:15:30  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130616 16:15:31  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 49 1885610091
130616 16:15:31 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130616 16:15:31 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.69'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `source-state` (`source`,`state`),
  KEY `first-last` (`firstname`,`lastname`),
  KEY `first-last-state` (`firstname`,`lastname`,`state`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=433924211 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySQL Config

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
wait_timeout=66600
net_read_timeout=66600
interactive_timeout=666666
max_allowed_packet=50G
max_connect_errors=666666
innodb_buffer_pool_size=22GB
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
thread_cache_size=4
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Solr data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
                driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databasename?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
                user="root"
                password="password"
                stream="true"/>
        <document name="content">
        <entity name="names" pk="id" query="SELECT id as solr_id, id,firstname, lastname, state from names limit 10000000">
                <field column="solr_id" name="solr_id" />
                <field column="id" name="id" />
              <field column="firstname" name="firstname" />
                <field column="lastname" name="lastname" />
              <field column="state" name="state" />
        </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create multiple root entities along with the `LIMIT` clause like -

```
<entity name="one" pk="id" query="SELECT id as solr_id, id,firstname, lastname, state from names limit 0, 10000000">
  <field column="solr_id" name="solr_id" />
  <field column="id" name="id" />
  <field column="firstname" name="firstname" />
  <field column="lastname" name="lastname" />
  <field column="state" name="state" />
</entity>
<entity name="two" pk="id" query="SELECT id as solr_id, id,firstname, lastname, state from names limit 10000000, 20000000">
  <field column="solr_id" name="solr_id" />
  <field column="id" name="id" />
  <field column="firstname" name="firstname" />
  <field column="lastname" name="lastname" />
  <field column="state" name="state" />
</entity>
```

until your required rows

**OR**

You can pass the `limit` and `offset` parameters as `request` paramters like -

```
<entity name="one" pk="id" query="SELECT id as solr_id, id,firstname, lastname, state from names limit ${dataimporter.request.startAt}, ${dataimporter.request.count}">
  <field column="solr_id" name="solr_id" />
  <field column="id" name="id" />
  <field column="firstname" name="firstname" />
  <field column="lastname" name="lastname" />
  <field column="state" name="state" />
</entity>
```

The query link for the second option would look like - `http://<hostname>:<port>/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&startAt=0&count=10000000`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the limit and offset approach.

Comment: Alright. Also if your problem is solved with this solution. Would you accept the answer?

Comment: This is a work around I am trying... Ill accept it this is the correct solution.

Comment: If you find another solution then please let me know too. It will be of great help to me.

Comment: Like the second option! Would it possible to run multiple DIH query link concurrently?

Answer (score 5):

Add batchSize="-1" to  data-config.xml

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq